# How often does the play store update its cache

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

I am wondering about how often the Play Store updates its cache. The thing is I am going to be implementing managed purchases ( once you buy you dont buy again). The thing is I have been reading around and alot of people say that the Play Store does not update its cache very often. 
The scenario. User makes a purchase on phone, then going to the tablet he does not have that purchase on the tablet, and querying the tablet does not show that that item has been purchased. 
How can I force the google play store cache to update without asking the user to purchase the item again (which will usually update the play store cache, as it comes back that the item has been purchased already).

So again how often does the Google Play Store update its local cache, and if it is just at device start and purchase request, is there another way to force the cache to update.

Comment: One way I know to refresh the cache is to clear data on the Play Store app. This can be done just by asking the user to do this manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered my on question but here is for others that might have this question:

I have found that the play store updates its cache on each purchase, and every couple of hours (when I canceled an order it updated within 3 hours usually, when i refunded an order a couple of days for refund the get through). So I can say from my own personal experience that the Play Store app updates its cache quite often, most likely after each time you turn it on. 
I think it is each time you turn it on because of how long it takes to turn on (getting all current info from google's servers, which I would expect your app purchase info to be among).

Also from the Google IO 2013 on they say google cache updates roughtly every 24 hours.

Comment: Does, will the play store clear its cache if the phone does not have internet for extended periods of time?